# Update existing PayloadCallback in Nearby Connections without reconnecting

Tags: android, google-nearby

I have my `MainActivity` connecting by Nearby Connections 2.0 to Rpi3 with Android Things installed. And I need to start `SecondActivity` or `ThirdActivity` depending on payload I've received in `MainActivity`. Either second and third activities have their own PayloadCallbacks. So in order to get Payload there, I have to disconnect in MainActivity and connect again in the new activity with new PayloadCallback set in acceptConnection() method.

Is there a way to save existing connection, but change PayloadCallback?

Code can be found on [github.com/Mkryglikov/BestCafe](https://github.com/Mkryglikov/BestCafe). I'm talking about `ConnectActivity` and `ActiveOrderActivity`

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern for what you're trying to do is to keep all your Nearby Connections code in one place (a class named something like NearbyConnectionsManager that all the Activities have access to), and to have all your different Activities register handlers with that class for the different BYTES Payloads you're expecting.

That way, NearbyConnectionsManager's onPayloadReceived() checks the value of the payloadString that it receives, and has a switch statement that invokes the handlePayloadString() callback method of the relevant Activity, thus keeping each Activity's logic contained within itself, while avoiding the need to disconnect and reconnect from your peers.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Service to encapsulate your Nearby Connections stuff (connection, events, errors, payloads), and allow your components like Activities and Fragments to bind and query the service (via an IBinder). Whether this service will be more persistent or short lived, it is up to your needs.